# Ubuntu says I'm out of space but I can't uninstall any programs

Tags: disk-usage

I have an ssd and an hdd, the latter of which is 1 TB. There are no games; there are a few ebooks and audiobooks, but I have no idea how it could be full. When I tried to uninstall a few programs, I got the message that I couldn't 'because there are no snap updates'. I'm running ubuntu 20.04 LTS.  Looking at the df output, I notice that /dev is invariably followed by loop and a number, so /dev/loopn; is this normal? Also,to du, the first time I ran it, it showed 67,496,896 bytes used; the second time it said 45,262,844. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: yes, snaps with /dev/loop is normal. If you paste the df output, it will help us see what you see and help you understand what's going on, specially regarding the disk size, total space and usage. I don't believe the snaps are relevant to your problem.

Comment: Don't vaguely describe error messages and output; show us the complete error messages and entire output. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1265140/edit) to copy/paste the information we need to advise you.